# runtime error 13 type mismatch

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I am running the below code where I am removing rows if the cell value contained in column no. 15 is not active and cell values in column 10 are not "e&d","vpg" and so on. It returns me this error: 'runtime error 13 type mismatch'.

Now, When I run it for a single condition it works for eg cell value = active or cell value = E&D, but adding multiple criteria returns me the error. Is the syntax wrong? I have even tried switching and instead of 'or', put the conditions in a bracket with commas separating them. For obvious reasons, it's not working because of syntax problems. Could anyone be kind enough to point out my mistake?

```
Sub test()
Dim n1, n2, x, z, lastrow As Variant



                  ' To delete entire row if criteria is not met
                    Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
                    Range("A4").Select
                    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
                    For x = lastrow To 4 Step -1
                      If Cells(x, 15).Value <> "Active" And (Cells(x, 10).Value <> "E&D" Or "ESG" Or "DLM SER" Or "VPD" Or "PLM PROD") Then
                      Rows(x).Delete
                      End If
                    Next x
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your if statement syntax is wrong, you need to specity the left-hand side multiple times like this

```
If Cells(x, 15).Value <> "Active" And (Cells(x, 10).Value <> "E&D" And Cells(x, 10).Value <> "ESG" And Cells(x, 10).Value <> "DLM SER" And Cells(x, 10).Value <> "VPD" And Cells(x, 10).Value <> "PLM PROD") Then
```

You also need to use and in this case rather than or because you want to check that all the conditions are true, i.e. none of the listed values are in cell x, 10

**Edit**

If you want to delete rows that are either not active OR the value in column 10 does not match you probably want to use the following

```
If Cells(x, 15).Value <> "Active" Or (Cells(x, 10).Value <> "E&D" And Cells(x, 10).Value <> "ESG" And Cells(x, 10).Value <> "DLM SER" And Cells(x, 10).Value <> "VPD" And Cells(x, 10).Value <> "PLM PROD") Then
```

Notice the or between the two main conditions

Comment: it did not work mate, yes the error is gone the statement is not checking the conditions

Comment: thanks gareth but i want the rows to be deleted 
first if not active then if the values are not met is "OR" the way to go ?
apparently it is thanks gareth

Comment: Yes, the new if statement will delete rows that are not active, if they are active it will still delete them if column 10 is not "E&D", "ESG", "DLM SER", "VPD" or "PLM PROD"